# Why do my poster colours behave strangely on my plastic palette?

Tags: paint, plastic, poster-color

I have poster paints - Camlin poster paints to be precise. I have 2 palettes, but both of them are plastic palettes. When I try to put a color on any of the palettes, they “go away”, like they don’t stay, the plastic kinda “absorbs” the color. Does this happen for everyone and do we have to use a palette made of another material or is there a solution to it?

By the color "goes away", I mean the consistency changes when the color touches the pallet. The brush also isn’t able to use the color mixture on the palette. As for the palette: as I said, it’s a plastic palette, meant for kids. I also have another palette, but it too is plastic and reacts with my poster paint the same way.

Comment: Do you mean your palette repels the paint, so it 'bunches up'?

Comment: Can you explain the state of the paint? Does the consistency or the color change when it's on the pallet or is it the same as before it touched the pallet? And what about the pallet? Does it still have color left after you washed it or does it change (become soft or soggy) when you put the paint on it? You can [edit] your question any time to add more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For new plastic palettes this is normal behaviour, and will go away after some usage.**
I looked into methods to get rid of this annoying aspect, but none seem to actually work well. Roughing the surface up will only make it harder to clean. I suggest to just bear with it, as it will eventually improve.

Alternatively, you can opt for a porcelain palette, which naturally has a less hydrophobic surface.

Comment: Hmm... my palette has been used tens of times, still it is reacting the same way. Also it is pretty old; at least 3yrs!

Comment: Age shouldn't really matter, and I really haven't come across a quicker method that actually makes the surface less repelling. What you can do is find an old plate, preferably porcelain, but most ceramics will work, either at home or from a thrift store, and work from that.

Answer (score 1):

Add a very small amount of dish soap (just a small drop on the tip of a small brush) to your paints when they are on the pallet. It will break the surface tension and allow the paint to “relax” onto your pallet.

Comment: I wouldn't want to mix soap in with my paints, as it will influence the structure and behaviour, and is likely bad for longevity, but I have seen this advice elsewhere. For projects that don't require archival properties, this apparently works.